# Sessions not recognized when going through flash / uploadify

Tags: php, jquery, flash, session, uploadify

I'm writing an application which uses cookie-based sessions for authentication.  All was well until I tried to integrate the uploadify jQuery plugin into my site.  I need uploadify to send the files to my `upload.php` file.  When I check the existence of any preknown session variables in that `upload.php` script, I get nothing. I've tried `print_r($_SESSION)` and got an empty array.

I'm not sure if this a problem with my php sessions code or my jquery uploadify code.  I'm somewhat new at both.

```
/**  INSIDE JQUERY **/
$('.fileUploadify').uploadify({
    'scriptData': {'filesUploaded':'1','PHPSESSID' : <?php echo json_encode(session_id()); ?>},
    ...


/**  UPLOAD.PHP **/
if(isset($_REQUEST['PHPSESSID'])) 
    session_id($_REQUEST['PHPSESSID']);

if(!isset($_GET['logout']) && isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['ipadd'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
    define('USERHASH',$_SESSION['user']);
    require_once('lib/ez_sql_core.php');
    require_once('lib/ez_sql_sqlite.php');
    require_once('lib/functions.php');
    $db = new ezSQL_sqlite('./'.USERHASH.'/','fileInformationBase.sqlite');
    $mdb = new ezSQL_sqlite('./','fileServMain.sqlite');

    $stats = $mdb->get_row("SELECT ID,bandwidthUsage,lastLogin,...
} else die('No no no');
```

The `upload.php` returns 'No no no` everytime. I've checked the session id, and it *is* sending to upload.php correctly.

On my normal page headers I'm not having this problem, where I'm simply starting the authorization section with `session_start()` and then the same `if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['ipadd] ...) {` line, which is working as expected.

---

#### Edit

This is the generated code for the jQuery script above

```
 'scriptData': {'filesUploaded':'1','PHPSESSID' :"m3vgn7j6a7nd3ckppnio1ln3e1" }
```

And putting an `echo $_REQUEST['PHPSESSID']` in the upload.php script prints out

```
'sjojolnjtcutbomceh50os3kg4'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the sessions that flash was seeing were old values. I don't know if they are cached or what. In any case, I had to "flush" the system out by deleting all SESSION cookies and starting over. Then it picked up the correct values. Hope this saves someone in the future some time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are telling your plugin to send session id via regular GET/POST parameter, it has to be enabled on the server. You should first debug this by viewing the network requests made from your browser (Firefox + FireBug addon is a good choice) to see whether or not your session id reaches the server.

If it does, consider .htaccess with:

```
php_flag        session.use_trans_sid           on       
php_flag        session.use_only_cookies        off
```

Comment: Why would I "need to enable it on the server" if I'm sending a simple string? The server doesn't know that's it a session id.

Comment: PHP will not initialize _SESSION array unless it knows its ID. there are two ways for a client to send it: via cookie, and via get/post parameter. If your client doesn't send the cookie, it sends a parameter (detectable in firebug), in which case php has to be configured to use non-cookie-based session ids.

Comment: There's more from session_id() manual: "If id is specified, it will replace the current session id. session_id() needs to be called before session_start() for that purpose. Depending on the session handler, not all characters are allowed within the session id. For example, the file session handler only allows characters in the range a-z A-Z 0-9 , (comma) and - (minus)!"